# get return value from bean in jboss

Tags: java, jboss, jbossfuse

```
package ats.emvo.routing;
```

public class routingpath {

```
public String RoutingPathToXml() {

    String requestLogPath ="file:///d:/in"; //(String) AtsBundleActivator.atsEmvoRoutingProperties.get("requestlogpath");
    return requestLogPath;

}
```

}

> i want to get this return string to bean in jboss fuse as route path 
>   up to now i called it like below in camel cxml,but i dont get the return value here.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd              http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">
    <camelContext id="cbr-example-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="_route1">
            <from id="_from1" uri="bean:routingInInterceptor"/>
            <to id="_to2" uri="file:///d:/out"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
    <bean class="ats.emvo.routing.routingpath" id="routingInInterceptor"/>
</blueprint>
```

Comment: If I understand correct, you want the returned string (file:///d:/in) to be put as a camel route from?

Comment: @ThemisPyrgiotis  yes..that's what i ment

Comment: I do not think you are in right way, that' s why i proposed something different. Please check my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

I will propose another approaches if you want to follow.

According to Camel, *"the bean: component binds beans to Camel message exchanges"*. So if you after a bean call print the Exchange message body you will see the contents coming form bean.

```
...
<uri="bean:routingInInterceptor"/>
<log message=Contents of bean: ${body}/> <!-- "file:///d:/in" -->
...
```

So information is put in Exchange.

In your case, you want to start your route "from" not from a hard-coded endpoint URI.

**Approach 1**
For that reason you can use **property placeholders in endpoint URIs**. So after you set up properties place holders you can have something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd              http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd"
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0">

    <!-- add file your-configuration-file.cfg with your properties under etc/ -->
    <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="your-configuration-file">      
        <cm:default-properties>
            <cm:property name="your.property" value="file:///d:/in"/>            
        </cm:default-properties>
    </cm:property-placeholder>

    <camelContext id="cbr-example-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="_route1">
            <from id="_from1" uri="{{your.property}}"/>
            <to id="_to2" uri="file:///d:/out"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>

    <!-- Actually bean is not needed since you will get the endpoint from properties file -->
    <bean class="ats.emvo.routing.routingpath" id="routingInInterceptor"/>
</blueprint>
```

More details about properties component http://camel.apache.org/properties.html.

**Approach 2**
Another aproach is to have dynamics endpoints with **toD** tag, to evaluate the endpoints on runtime. So, you can have something like

```
<route id="_route1">
    <from id="_from1" uri="${header.dynamicUri}}"/>
    <to id="_to2" uri="file:///d:/out"/>
</route>
```

More deatils about are in http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html at section *Dynamic To*.

Comment: can i have a small demo with java class and camel content

Comment: I just edit the approach 1, and put configurations inside.

Comment: my senario is xml files comes to my jboss server there is a java class to identify the xml root tag and according to tag it will save on different folders . i want to take that file backs and trasform xml after route those file in to another location

Comment: I am sorry but this is not what you are asking! If my answer fits you then accepted, if not wait for another one. But what you are saying in comment is something completely different, so ask a new question. But before you do that see examples of Jboss Fuse (they come with installation), it has exactly what you need.